# Trying to increase speed of bulk inserts in Sqlite.

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a databaseHelper class in which I have the following function:

```
public SQLiteDatabase returnDB(){

        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    }
```

In my main class(Async Task -- onPreExecute):

```
            dbHelper = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            dbHelper.open(); 

            mDb = dbHelper.returnDB(); 
            mDb.beginTransaction();
```

In doInBackground I process the query like:

```
dbHelper.insert(dateToInsert, CONTACT_NAME, String.valueOf(days), String.valueOf(hou), CONTACT_IMAGE_URI, String.valueOf(min),String.valueOf(mon), String.valueOf(secon), CONTACT_ID, String.valueOf(weeks), String.valueOf(years));
```

Then in onPostExecute:

```
mDb.endTransaction();
dbHelper.close();
```

But I get a database locked error, when I try to fetch values into listview immediately after the execution of Async task. Below is the LogCat:

```
02-08 14:40:06.587: E/SQLiteLog(6394): (5) database is locked
02-08 14:40:06.588: D/SQLiteConnection(6394): executeForString took 2505ms - failed, sql="PRAGMA journal_mode", exception="database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode"
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.exa.birthdayrem/databases/Bdr'.
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:627)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:313)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:287)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:860)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at com.exa.birthdayrem.DBAdapter.returnDB(DBAdapter.java:156)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at com.exa.birthdayrem.LoaderClass$MagicCall.onPostExecute(LoaderClass.java:457)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at com.exa.birthdayrem.LoaderClass$MagicCall.onPostExecute(LoaderClass.java:1)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-08 14:40:06.602: E/SQLiteDatabase(6394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

#### Am I doing this right? I dont see much of a performance boost though?

Comment: Are you really sure that the AsyncTask is finished when you try to read? The "Database is locked" normally happens when one thread is writing and another is reading or writing

Comment: First of all I am not sure if I am doing ti the right way, all the examples I found on the net dont use a dataabse Helper class so I have to fetch my SQLiteDatabase variable from thet class first. then I create an obj of dbHelper in main class and use that to insert, I want to check if this is right?

Comment: Maybe you could use a locking mechanism in your dbHelper (see ReentrantLock), but this would also prevent multiple readers at a time.

Comment: I am using the lock, however I am more concerned about the way I am doing this, is it right?

Comment: So if you are talking about performance of the insert statement: If you do an insert without starting a transaction, SQLite is doing this implicite. So a single insert has the same performance, no matter if you start a transaction or not. If you have multiple inserts, it will be much faster within a transaction.

Comment: Yes I have 109 records, for each record there are fifteen inserts into three tables. I think it should be boosted up. The way I see the tutorial is different with what I am doing I am just confused about the mDb variable. Refer: http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html

Comment: I dont see any advantage in passing a reference to the DB out of the helper. I normally create an insert method for each required object type in the helper. In this insert method, I start the transaction, do the inserts and close the transaction again. If you require transactions over the inserts of multiple object types, create a wrapper method for begin and commit.

Comment: Can you provide me some sample code? Even I am using a insert method in helper class but I am calling this insert method once for each record, means 109 times. But there are other insert methods too. Should I batch all the insert methods together in one function in the helper itself?

Comment: Ok, I added an example as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can handle transactions in a DatabaseHelper. You need to make sure that the Helper is created only once, e.g. by making it a Singleton. For better performance with multiple readers at the same time you could replace the ReentrantLock by a ReadWriteLock.

```
DbHelper helper = new DbHelper();

private void DoSimpleInsert()
{
    helper.InsertA(items);
}

private void DoComplexInsert()
{
    helper.BeginTransaction();
    helper.InsertA(items);
    helper.InsertB(items);
    helper.EndTransaction();
}

public class DbHelper
{
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private boolean isExpliciteTransaction;
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        isExpliciteTransaction = true;
        db.beginTransaction();
    }

    public void EndTransaction()
    {
        isExpliciteTransaction = false;
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    public void InsertA(ClassA[] items)
    {
        lock.lock();
        try
        {
            if (!isExpliciteTransaction)
            {
                db.beginTransaction();
            }

            // Do the inserts here

            if (!isExpliciteTransaction)
            {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void InsertB(ClassB[] items)
    {
        lock.lock();
        try
        {
            if (!isExpliciteTransaction)
            {
                db.beginTransaction();
            }

            // Do the inserts here

            if (!isExpliciteTransaction)
            {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```